# scipy.linalg.eig returns left, right eigenvector matrices which are not orthogonal to each other

Tags: scipy

I've seen a number of posts similar to this one, but none of them seem to answer my question:  If a nonsymmetric matrix has distinct, real eigenvalues, why are the matrices of left, right eigenvectors not orthogonal to each other?

Minimal example:

```
from scipy import linalg
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
w, vl, vr = linalg.eig(A, left=True)
vl.T @ vr
```

Returns:

```
array([[ 9.61890662e-01,  1.19810550e-16,  4.80378434e-17],
   [ 2.42776270e-16,  9.61890662e-01, -8.65237511e-17],
   [-9.42917880e-17, -1.02266004e-16,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: You do realise that the returned array is an identity matrix of order 2, put aside the numerical errors?

Comment: Note that the magnitudes of all the off-diagonal elements are less than 2.5e-16.  Given [normal floating point imprecision](https://floating-point-gui.de/), it is reasonable to say that those vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Ah -- yes, I'm not worried about the off-diagonal elements.  It's the 0.961's that bother me.  Just computing the right evec's and then inverting that matrix fixes things.  I was just curious if there was something I was doing wrong with eig + left=True.